# Use property value within a property file

Tags: java, properties-file

I have property file with the below key value pairs, rather repeating a particular value can I declare that initially and use that key dynamically within other parts of file. I am looking this sonar-project.properties file.

Original file

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=com.company.somecompany::AppName
sonar.projectName=BR_BRANCH_JAN/AppName
sonar.projectVersion=2.3.1

# Comma-separated paths to directories with sources (required)
sonar.sources=src/main/java/
#, src/test/java/
sonar.java.binaries=target/AppName-WAR-2.3.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/
sonar.java.libraries=target/AppName-WAR-2.3.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar
sonar.jacoco.reportMissing.force.zero=true

# Code coverage via unit tests
sonar.junit.reportPaths=target/surefire-reports
sonar.jacoco.reportPaths=target/jacoco.exec
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=target/jacoco.exec
sonar.surefire.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports

# Language
sonar.language=java

# Encoding of the source files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

I wanted to modify this something like this

```
app.name=AppName
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=com.company.somecompany::${app.name}
sonar.projectName=BR_BRANCH_JAN/${app.name}
sonar.projectVersion=2.3.1

# Comma-separated paths to directories with sources (required)
sonar.sources=src/main/java/
#, src/test/java/
sonar.java.binaries=target/${app.name}-WAR-${sonar.projectVersion}-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/
sonar.java.libraries=target/${app.name}-WAR-${sonar.projectVersion}-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar
sonar.jacoco.reportMissing.force.zero=true

# Code coverage via unit tests
sonar.junit.reportPaths=target/surefire-reports
sonar.jacoco.reportPaths=target/jacoco.exec
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=target/jacoco.exec
sonar.surefire.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports

# Language
sonar.language=java

# Encoding of the source files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Quick google, here's [an article about exactly that](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/04/a-way-to-read-properties-with-variable-interpolation.html)

Comment: Thanks much. Somehow my search was bad. Will give a try and update here once it works.

Comment: @NimrodArgov looks like SonarQube don't like the ${} kind. I am getting error as "ERROR: Invalid value of sonar.sources for com.company.somecompany::${app.name}